# Python Django - Are periods in a string processed correctly when retrieved from an api?

Tags: python, django

In Python to include a period in a string you need to add the escape key `\` in front of the period `.`

so `"example\.com"` appears as `"example.com"`

say I'm programming in Django and a Python SDK returns a specific url such as `"example.com/abcdef"`

I assume I don't have to worry about adding a `\.` to `"example.com/abcdef"` so that it is  `"example\.com/abcdef"`. Can you explain the reason why I don't need to add the `\.` in this case.

Comment: Are you asking about DRF or Django? Your question is about the json response from API?

Comment: I'm asking about just Django, not Django Rest Framework

Comment: For a regular expression `.` means *any character*, so it would also match `exampleacom` for example...

Comment: I understand `.` means any character. I'm asking why I don't need to process a Python SDK returns a specific url such as "example.com/abcdef", I assume the . in the return from SDK would be assumed by python to be a . and not any character